# Using an enum as part of an index definition

Tags: mysql, index, order-by, enum

When I use an `ENUM` column in a table the `ORDER BY` uses the ordinal of the `ENUM` not its value. I wasn't aware of that.
So my question is what are the subtle issues when an `ENUM` is part of an index definition? Is it an antipattern or bad idea?

Comment: ENUM can be indeed an antipattern.. if you need to support an new type you must ALTER TABLE to support that new type.. most off the times this will lock out the table for some time.. note MYSQL 5.6 has live ALTER TABLE capabilities what doesn't lock the table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland:Yes I know that.I am asking only in relation to indexing

Comment: i readed the question wrong but you already know that.. well isn't easy to query distinct values from an ENUM.. maybe the MySQL optimizer could have trouble with it and choose not to use that index..

Comment: And well if your need to ORDER BY... you need to do ORDER BY FIELD(enum_field, values)  that will use an filesort (quicksort) pass for sure

Comment: And joins on ENUM will be bad because MySQL needs to lookup index positions off the strings that you want to join. so yes indexing on ENUM is pretty useless..

Comment: That's an extreme overstatement.  The optimizer resolves the string equivalents into integers.  Indexing an enum is extremely valuable for equality ref lookups against an enum and grouping by an enum, just not so much for ordering.

Comment: As a general rule I follow, if the field does not have more than 10 unique values in it, do not index it. Your index will likely be ignored but still maintained on IUD ops. Since this is an enum, I assume there are only a few items?